# How to check/uncheck a checkbox in pure JS using an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, checked

**Here is my code:**

```js
function toggleOffer() {
    let toggleButton = document.getElementById("select-time");
    if (toggleButton.checked = true){
        toggleButton.checked= false;
    }else{
        toggleButton.checked= true;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
   <p onclick="toggleOffer()">1 mois</p>
   <input type="checkbox" id="select-time" checked>
   <p onclick="toggleOffer()">12 mois</p>
</div>
```

It works one way: when my checkbox is checked and I click on either `<p>`, the checkbox gets unchecked, but I can't get the other way round to work.

Comment: Recheck this line: `if (toggleButton.checked = true){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having a problem because you're using an assignment operator, `=`, when a comparison operator, `==` is appropriate, as a few others have said.

The following, corrected javascript should therefore work:

```js
function toggleOffer() {
  let toggleButton = document.getElementById("select-time");
  if (toggleButton.checked == true) {
    toggleButton.checked = false;
  } else {
    toggleButton.checked = true;
  }
}
```

Actually, there's no need to ever use `== true` or `== false` in javascript anyway. You could simplify your code further to this:

```js
function toggleOffer() {
  let toggleButton = document.getElementById("select-time");
  if (toggleButton.checked) {
    toggleButton.checked = false;
  } else {
    toggleButton.checked = true;
  }
}
```

Or, because of the way that the `.checked` property works in javascript:

```js
function toggleOffer() {
  toggleButton.checked = !toggleButton.checked;
}
```

This always sets the checkbox to the opposite boolean value, which is the same as toggling it.

---

But I would also like to add that you could achieve this behaviour completely without javascript using `label` elements.

This would be my preferred way to do this:

```html
<div>
   <label for="select-time">1 mois</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="select-time" checked>
   <label for="select-time">12 mois</label>
</div>
```

Change your `p` element to `label`, and add a `for` attribute specifying the `id` of the checkbox they are meant to toggle.

In your case, `for="select-time"` for both labels, because you want both labels to toggle the checkbox.

Comment: Many thanks, I wanted to do it in JS bc I am training. :)

Comment: @Marion In that case, I would still recommend a different javascript solution to the one in the accepted answer, namely: `toggleButton.checked = !toggleButton.checked;`. See the third code block in my post above. It's usually a good idea to keep code as short as possible!

Answer (score 0):

'toggleButton.checked = true' is setting the value rather than comparing it, what you need to do is change it to the following 
`if(toggleButton.checked === true){...`
or since it is boolean value in question just simply do this
`if(toggleButton.checked){...`

I would even propose the cleaner way is to do it like this.
Instead of this

```
if (toggleButton.checked === true){
    toggleButton.checked= false;
}else{
    toggleButton.checked= true;
}
```

just do this `toggleButton.checked = !toggleButton.checked`

Answer (score 0):

Your'e setting the value of checked inside the if statement instead of checking for it.

You can remove the comparison inside the if statement:

```
if (toggleButton.checked) { ... }
```

Or use ==/=== instead:

```
if (toggleButton.checked === true) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `if(toggleButton.checked===true)` instead of `if(toggleButton.checked=true)`

Answer (score 0):

you can try to reverse boolean (true/false) with '!'

`toggleButton.check = !toggleButton.check`

`!toggleButton.check` is the reverse of `toggleButton.check`

for you it's something like this

```
function toggleOffer() {
    let toggleButton = document.getElementById("select-time");
    toggleButton.check = !toggleButton.check
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleOffer() {
        let toggleButton = document.getElementById("select-time");
        if(!toggleButton) return;
        toggleButton.checked = !toggleButton.checked;
    }
```

Or in one go

```
<p onclick="((el)=>{el.checked = !el.checked})(document.getElementById('select-time') || {})">12 mois</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the problem that `toggleButton.checked = true` should be `toggleButton.checked === true` (or just `toggleButton.checked`) it is generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers. Try adding event handling to the document, and using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). Something like (function simplified):

```js
document.addEventListener("click", toggleOffer);

function toggleOffer(evt) {
  if (evt.target.dataset.offer) {
    const checkBox = document.querySelector("#select-time");
    checkBox.checked = !checkBox.checked;
  }
}
```

```css
p[data-offer] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p data-offer="0">1 mois</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="select-time" checked>
<p data-offer="1">12 mois</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this with your current javascript code and it'll work:

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementById("select-time");

function toggleOffer() {
  if (toggleButton.checked == true){
    toggleButton.checked= false;
  } else {
    toggleButton.checked= true;
  }
}
```